# is it possible to write jquery methods that can only be called by elements created within a plugin?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

Sorry if that question was a bit unclear. Let me try to explain.

I am starting to learn to write jQuery plugins. I have a method of the plugin that is private and is called like so:

```
var $curPgInf = getPgInf($('#content1_0'));
```

I don't know if it is any better performance-wise, but it seems cleaner to me (and I'm mostly curious to see if/how it can be done) to be able to call it like this instead:

```
var $curPgInf = $('#content1_0').getPgInf();
```

I know that I can use:

```
$.fn.getPgInf = function(obj) {
    // return the page info...
}
```

but that makes the function public...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery plugin extends the jQuery object, so every function you add to `$-jQuery` will be public.
(The `fn` property is the prototype of the jQuery object.)

After that short explanation, the answer is, **NO**, you can't extend jQuery with a private function.